# Attempting to find how many specific categorical variable come before another categorical variable

Tags: python, pandas

Data:

```
       event_date event
99652  2014-06-11    DX
2533   2014-08-01    DX
2534   2014-08-01    RX
0      2014-12-11    DX
293494 2015-06-16    RX
2020   2015-08-04    DX
2021   2015-08-04    RX
99653  2015-08-04    DX
1      2015-12-14    DX
```

As you can see, the data is ordered from oldest to newest. What I want to know is how many DXs happen before the first RX.

Not sure how to do this in an efficient manner.

EDIT: I should have mentioned that we need to check that the first value isn't something other than DX.

Comment: Expected output? Do you want to find every DX for every RX?

Comment: I wanted to find the count of DX before the first RX. I came up with a solution below but I'd appreciate it if you could take a look and see if you can think of anything more efficient

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46899282/attempting-to-find-how-many-specific-categorical-variable-come-before-another-ca#comment80746377_46899455) based on your edit, and please accept Vaishali's answer if it helped.

Answer (score 2):

Given that the data is ordered,

```
df.reset_index().event.eq('RX').idxmax()
```

It prints

```
2
```

Option 2 (much faster):

```
(df.event != 'RX').cumprod().sum()
```

Edit: Based on the update,

```
(df.event == 'DX').cumprod().sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up figuring it out:

```
count = 0
for i in test.index.values:
    if (test.loc[test.index.values[0],"event"] in ("NonVertFX", "VertFX", "PX", "RX")):
        count = -1
        print("first value is not DX")
        break

    if (test.loc[i,"event"] == "RX"):
        break
    count += 1
print(count)
```